# RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage Insufficient Privileges

Tags: community, oauth2, partner-communities, insufficient-privileges, remote-access

While logged in community as Partner Community Licence user I am making a oauth with external system using special button and last redirect is a **RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp** with ***?source=*** parameter containing long string of random 976 characters.

At this moment I am encountering a

[image: Insufficient Privileges You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.]

Any ideas what permissions I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Solution for this problem was to **activate a community** (was in
>   preview state) then all community users will get an email with link to
>   create a new password.
>
> After creating new one, user will be able to pass that error.

So Insufficient Privileges was probably caused by missing password for a user.

Answer (score 0):

In Partner profile, Please check whether the VF page(RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp) you've mentioned is added to the "Enabled Visualforce Page Access" section.

Comment: RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage does not exist in Enabled Visualforce Page Access probably because it is a build in class.